# NodeJS and React Concurrent servers on different Ports

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, shared-hosting

**Story:** Recently, We started developing Front-end for an application using `'create-react-app'`. It was working great on our development machine back then.

After some time, We started the NodeJS APIs development using express and then connected it to our React Front-End. Still everything was working great on our development machine.

**Problem:** As we are done now with the development, and wanted to host the Application on 3rd Party Server (*A2Hosting*); We are having issues in starting the Server and React App concurrently.

If we start the Server alone, It is working and we are able to call the apis. If we start the React App alone we still are getting desirable results. But problem persists if we try run both. Below is the error report when we try to run the server and client concurrently:

```
$ concurrently --kill-others-on-fail "yarn server" "yarn client"
[0] node[3989326]: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
[1] node[3989327]: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
[0] yarn server exited with code SIGABRT
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[1] yarn client exited with code 1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: First hand suggestion would be to build your react app, then put it somewhere in your node application folder then try to serve your react app within your node itself. Actually ignore webpack server that `create-react-app` establish.

Comment: That's a decent dev setup but complicates things in prod. You can serve the built React app from Express to simplify it. Have a look at this example setup I put together: https://github.com/textbook/cyf-app-starter